# Java - String.join() does not equal its string

Tags: java, string

I have `list = [1,0,1]`, but each number in the List are of type String. I do

```
if ( String.join("",list) == "101"){ 
    return true
}
```

As you can see, these to Strings are equal but it won't return true.

Comment: Use equals, not ==

Comment: `==` is fit your requirement, please use `str1.equals(str2)`

Comment: ok the answer is to use `.equals`. I am assuming you didnt know the difference between using `==` and `.eqauls`. I recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: using equals

```
if ( String.join("",list).equals("101")){ 
    return true
}
```